# Angular library no making HTTP calls

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have build angular library using this [Generator](https://github.com/jvandemo/generator-angularjs-library) all the functions of the library works fine when i call them from the app but, the functions that make `HTTP` calls are not working. Is there any reason preventing from making `HTTPS` calls from an Angular library !

Here is a code sample of the the library code:

```
(function (angular) {

  // Create all modules and define dependencies to make sure they exist
  // and are loaded in the correct order to satisfy dependency injection
  // before all nested files are concatenated by Gulp

  // Config
  angular.module('myLib.config', [])
      .value('myLib.config', {
          debug: true
      });

  // Modules
  angular.module('myLib.directives', []);
  angular.module('myLib.services', []);
  angular.module('myLib',
      [
          'myLib.config',
          'myLib.directives',
          'myLib.services'
      ]);

})(angular);

(function (angular) {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('myLib.services', [])
        .factory('myLib', myLib);

        myLib.$inject = ['$http', '$rootScope'];
        function myLib($http, $rootScope) {

            var myLibrary = {};

         myLibrary.register = function() {
          $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'url', 
            data: {id: '00000000000'},
            headers: {'Authorization': 'Basic ' + credentialsEncoded}
          });
        };


            return myLibrary;
        }
})(angular);
```

when am trying to call the register function the HTTP call is not made however, call another functions is working fine.

Comment: do u minify ur library?

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean exactly? any code sample?

Comment: yes, but i also tried the un-minified version

Comment: All the clues you need are in network tab of browser dev tools. Inspect each request there. Also add some error handling for those requests. Information provided is almost useless for anyone to troubleshoot from

Comment: I have already checked the network requests there is no requests are made, when calling the function register showing the in the sample code above.

Answer (score 0):

With `$http(...)` you create a so called promise. To execute the query simply call

```
$http({...}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
}, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
});
```

See the official [Angular $http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) documentation for more information about the callbacks.